# How to redirect dynamic pages using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have moved site from one framework to another and now I would like to redirect important pages (around 20). How to redirect them using apache rewrite? Here are examples:

```
Old: http://mydomain.com/ba/stream.php?kat=15
New: http://www.mydomain.com/bs/about-us/our-partners

Old: http://mydomain.com/ba/stream.php?kat=29
New: http://www.mydomain.com/bs/catalogues/it-catalogue
```

Also, after important pages are listed, I'd like to redirect all remaining links in form:

```
http://mydomain.com/ba/whatever-is-here
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/bs/
```

Following TerryE's suggestion, I'll attach my latest code which is not working :)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^kat=15$
RewriteRule ^stream\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/bs/about-us/our-partners [R=301,L]
```

One more note: I use this code to redirect root domain to www subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have placed this  root to www code below code for specific pages redirection, and when I test `http://mydomain.com/ba/stream.php?kat=15` in browser, I am redirected to `http://www.mydomain.com/bs/ba/stream.php?kat=15`

Comment: What have you tried or researched?  Have you read any rewrite examples using `%{QUERY_STRING}` conditions?  We are here to help, not to do your thinking for you.

Comment: I am sorry if I have offended you. I spent hours researching, trying and testing with no luck. That is why I asked. I know this should be easy to do, that is why I have not attached any code I have tried.

Comment: @AdnanKurtovic: Showing your attempts, even if they don't work, a) shows a good faith effort on your part, b) helps answerers understand what you're trying to do, and c) helps answerers who might have tried the same thing (in some cases, it might not be as easy as you think it is).

Comment: Note taken. I listened and edited my question.

Comment: Adnan, no you haven't offended me and sorry if I implied that.  It's just the question form points you to guidelines [asking help »](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which we expect you to read.  If you can't be bothered to do this, then perhaps you shouldn't be surprised if we can't be bothered to reply :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adnan,

You need to add the following lines to your `DOCROOT/.htaccess`.  This assumes that you don't have any `.htaccess` file in your `ba` subdirectory.  (See [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules) for an explanation of why.)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
#
# Redirect kat 15 to the Partners page 
#
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^kat=15$
RewriteRule ^ba/stream\.php$  http://www.mydomain.com/bs/about-us/our-partners? [R=301,L]
#
# Redirect all other kat ids to the corresponding bs page 
#
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^kat=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^ba/stream\.php$  http://www.mydomain.com/bs/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Note:

- the rule matches against the UPI less the leading path (in this case /)
- you need to have the trailing ? on the replacement string to suppress the existing query parameters.
- the **%n** parameters pick up the match variables from the last successful condition match.

Comment: Thank you @TerryE your suggestion really did the trick. One more thing that is left is to redirect all other pages in format `http://mydomain.com/ba/stream.php?kat=12`, where 12 represents any number to subfolder `bs`. Could you help me with this please, as well? I have tried adding this code `RewriteRule ^ba/* /bs/$1 [R=301,L]` but it does not work. I have tried `RewriteRule ^ba/(.*)$ /bs/$1 [R=301,L]` as well with similar result :)

Comment: @AdnanKurtovic, I've added the extra lines that you need.  It would help if you read the mod_rewrite docs which explain this ;-?  BTW how about a tick for ans :-)

Comment: thank you very much. When I need to use this I usually solve that particular problem I have, but I will definitely have to sit and learn it properly. Thanks once more.